# RowSpan and ColumnSpan in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, layout, grid, xamarin.forms

Is there anyone out there who can explain to me how `RowSpan` and `ColumnSpan` work in `Xamarin.Forms`?
The parameters right, left, top, and bottom are a little bit confusing.

Let's use this code snippet for `RowSpan`:

```
grid.Children.Add(new Label
{
   Text = "Span two rows (or more if you want)",
   TextColor = Color.Yellow,
   BackgroundColor = Color.Navy,
   XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
   YAlign = TextAlignment.Center
}, 2, 3, 1, 3);
```

What do the numbers 2, 3, 1, 3 mean in terms of columns and rows here?
This is for a grid with four rows and three columns.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This answer is copied and pasted from [this answer at Xamarin's forums (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507000924/http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/99606/) by Till Balandat, but is useful here since Xamarin's documentation doesn't seem to  explain the additional parameters to the Add method.

The overload for Add that takes 4 parameters is a little confusing, but in the end lets you define Row, RowSpan, Column and Columnspan:
So the above example

```
var label = new Label { Text = "Row 1" };
myGrid.Children.Add(label,0,0);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(label,2);
```

translates to:

```
var label = new Label { Text = "Row 1" };
myGrid.Children.Add(label, 0, 2, 0, 1);
```

This is what Xamarin does internally:

```
public void Add(View view, int left, int right, int top, int bottom)
{
    //..exceptionhandling removed
    Grid.SetRow((BindableObject) view, top);
    Grid.SetRowSpan((BindableObject) view, bottom - top);
    Grid.SetColumn((BindableObject) view, left);
    Grid.SetColumnSpan((BindableObject) view, right - left);
    this.Add(view);
}
```

So you might be more comfortable with something like this:

```
public static class GridExtension
{
    public static void AddChild(this Grid grid, View view, int row, int column, int rowspan = 1, int columnspan = 1)
    {
        if (row < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("row");
        if (column < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("column");
        if (rowspan <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("rowspan");
        if (columnspan <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("columnspan");
        if (view == null)
          throw new ArgumentNullException("view");
        Grid.SetRow((BindableObject)view, row);
        Grid.SetRowSpan((BindableObject) view, rowspan);
        Grid.SetColumn((BindableObject) view, column);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan((BindableObject) view, columnspan);
        grid.Children.Add(view);      
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: (It just took me half an hour) - Setting the ColumnSpan to something heighter than 1 is NOT working if a Grid has no RowDefinitions, even on a single line grid... (At least in a Xamarin Forms UWP App)